# как сделать так, что бы пользователь мог ввести числа через пробел?

Tags: python

```
massiv = []
ryad = int(input('Количество рядков: '))
stolb = int(input('Количество столбиков: '))
for i in range(ryad):
    massiv.append([])
    for j in range(stolb):
        massiv[i].append(int(input('Введи число ')))
for i in range(ryad):
    massiv[i].sort()
print(massiv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Все очень просто. Сначала пользователь вводит например 2 3 4 5 6 2 4 5 в `string`, тоесть все это будет одна строка, далее для того чтобы получить по отдельности все эти числа в массив нужно использовать `split()`

Как пользоватся split(): https://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/razbienie-strok-cherez-split-v-python.html